# how to remove "empty" space between subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot, imshow

I'm making a figure with a total of 68 subplots and want to remove the empty space between them all. Here's what I have:

[image: plot with too much space].

How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: using plt.tight_layout() makes it even worse:

[image: even more space between the subplots]

Here's my code:

```
for j in range(0,len(sort_yf)):
for i in range(0,len(yf)):
    if yf[i]==sort_yf[j]:
        sort_ID=np.append(sort_ID,'output/'+ID[i]+'.png')
for i in range (1,69):
    plt.subplot(17,4,i,aspect='equal')
    plots=img.imread(sort_ID[i])
    plt.imshow(plots)
    plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I guess the answer to this question is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071947/how-to-remove-the-space-between-subplots-in-matplotlib-pyplot) as none of the answers here are really useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried the tight layout functionality?

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

See also [HERE](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html)

**EDIT**: Alternatively, you can use [gridspec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#adjust-gridspec-layout):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
images = [np.random.rand(40, 40) for x in range(68)]
gs = mpl.gridspec.GridSpec(17, 4)
gs.update(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1, left=0.1, right=0.4, bottom=0.1, top=0.9) 
for i in range(68):
    plt.subplot(gs[i])
    plt.imshow(images[i])
    plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, just tried this and unfortunately it didn't work. For some reason it seemed to make the problem worse.

Comment: How did it get worse?
Moreover, can you modify your example code snippet such that in can be executed? For instance, you did not specify `sort_yf`.

Comment: each of the images actually got smaller, i'll upload an image of what i mean. I cant really because it requires a csv file and a folder full of images which are reasonably large.

Comment: I guess gridspec may work in your case, see my editing of the post

Answer (score 4):

Adjust the whitespace around the subplots with:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.01,hspace=0.01)
```

In my example I just modified wspace and hspace. You can also adapt the positions. Consider the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust).

You could also modify the [GridSpec Layout](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#adjust-gridspec-layout).