# Difficulty changing horizontal space between Matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, whitespace

In Python I was making a graph of multiple sub-barplots, and eventually decided, for aesthetic purposes, to try and remove the horizontal whitespace between them, but this seemingly easy task is not working out somehow.

My current graph looks like this,

[image]

And the code to generate it is this,

```
## The data first, pardon its length
data = {'n_size: 10, scale: 5': {'Normal_data': {'T_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.9665604111322623,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.1403044027874627},
   'Normal_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.3588016310928018,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.15670772400999605}},
  'T_data': {'T_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.9571050544498441,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.4919716194794976},
   'Normal_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.33135961083598975,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.09517290555081247}}},
 'n_size: 10, scale: 10': {'Normal_data': {'T_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.9641872823759053,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.12880945204032987},
   'Normal_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.5566844810693337,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.16096047896246227}},
  'T_data': {'T_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.6216338568355548,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.7082362141795221},
   'Normal_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.3948692029244512,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.18799991442400232}}},
 'n_size: 10, scale: 20': {'Normal_data': {'T_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.9680652106664631,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.11374246421698583},
   'Normal_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.7466108597314576,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.15341975348920403}},
  'T_data': {'T_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 1.1329410521346626,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.09506974062859724},
   'Normal_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.6864829731707396,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.13872252491967219}}},
 'n_size: 10, scale: 30': {'Normal_data': {'T_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.933652508907905,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.03935646501763717},
   'Normal_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.8218968469603595,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.13640544525624385}},
  'T_data': {'T_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.9965691581931089,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.05996151343132031},
   'Normal_model': {'% model_mean_accuracy': 0.8539754983373469,
    '% model_std_accuracy': 0.012542281271065603}}}}


def draw_barplots(data, rows_columns_length = 5):

    fig=plt.figure()  

#     plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.0)
#     fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.0)

    ## Calculating the correct # of rows/columns for whole figure
    n_cols = rows_columns_length
    n_rows = len(data) / rows_columns_length
    if not (n_rows).is_integer():
        n_rows = n_rows + 1      

#     matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(n_rows, n_cols, wspace=0.0)

    for i, var_name in enumerate(data):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(n_rows, n_cols, i+1)

        width = 0.5
        ax.bar(x = [0], height = [data[var_name]['Normal_data']['T_model']['% model_mean_accuracy']],
               width=width, label = 'T_model'
              )
        ax.bar(x = [0.5], height = [data[var_name]['Normal_data']['Normal_model']['% model_mean_accuracy']],
              width=width, label='Normal_model'
              )

        ax.set_title(var_name, size=8.5)
        ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
        ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

#     plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.0)
#     fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.0)
#     matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(n_rows, n_cols, wspace=0.0) 

    plt.show()

draw_barplots(data, 2)
```

I have tried setting `plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.0)` and `matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(n_rows, n_cols, hspace=0.0)`, as per these answers ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408572/how-to-remove-empty-space-between-subplots?noredirect=1&lq=1), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41071947/how-to-remove-the-space-between-subplots-in-matplotlib-pyplot)), but they seem not to work.

How can I understand what is going on?

Comment: your question doesn’t use gridspec so hard to tell why the hspace and wspace arguments aren’t working for you.

Comment: To change the horizontal space you need to use `wspace` ("***w***idth-space"), *not* `hspace` ("***h***eight-space").

Comment: ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I changed it to `wspace`, and I still have the same problem, it is still not working for me.

Also, I tried putting gridspec in multiple places in my code, to no avail, so I did try to incorporate it.

Comment: Note the first comment: You neither show your attempt to use `plt.subplots_adjust`, nor the attempt to use `gridspec.GridSpec`. So one cannot help further (other than assuring you that both will *in principle* work fine).

Comment: I have now added in as commented lines everything I had tried in the code to make the horizontal space go away; apologies for the delay in producing a full MWE.

Comment: If I uncomment the first commented line (`plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.0)`) and run the code, the result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iywdq.png), where there is no horizontal space between the subplots, as expected.

Comment: I just now (a day later) double-checked using the line of code you pointed out, and it  works for me now, producing the same graph as you posted. I looked over all my code, and it looks like my matplotlib settings were somehow interfering with subplot spacing. `matplotlib.rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})` seems to have been the culprit, so I'll have to watch out for that next time. Thanks a lot for the help and patience dealing with this!